# How to copy String from SavedPreferences to Spanned?

Tags: android, string, spanned

I'm trying to get a String from SavedPreferences and put it's contents into a Spanned class so it can be displayed in an EditText field using Html markup. I have pasted my current code below however I see why it doesn't work as a String and Spanned are not the same types...does anyone know of a good way around this?

```
public class SavedItemsActivity extends ItemsActivity {

private static SharedPreferences saveditems;

@Override
public Spanned getItem() {
    Spanned item = null;
    item = Html.fromHtml(saveditems.getString("CurrentSavedItem",""));
    return item;
}
```

I am unable to pass the string to the EditText directly. I tried using the below code (where 'itemtext' is the EditText):

```
ItemGenActivity.itemtext.setText(Html.fromHtml(saveditemss.getString("CurrentSavedItem",""));
```

The EditText is declared in the other ItemGenActivity as below:

```
public EditText itemtext
```

Comment: I fail to see the problem. You are parsing the HTML with `Html.fromHtml()`. The result of that can be passed to `setText()` on an `EditText`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot modify `ItemGenActivity` from another activity. `ItemGenActivity` can load the `SharedPreferences` and apply the value to its own `EditText`.